# How to optimize UIPageViewController to have re-using mechanism similar to tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

So far, most of the `UIPageViewController` tutorial I encounter, will create `UIViewController` on the fly, when being swiped to desired page.

### Example of UIPageViewController, without optimization

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    let dataSource = ["View Controller One", "View Controller Two", "View Controller Three", "View Controller Four"]

    var currentViewControllerIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        configurePageViewController()
    }

    func configurePageViewController() {

        guard let pageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: CustomPageViewController.self)) as? CustomPageViewController else {
            return
        }

        pageViewController.delegate = self
        pageViewController.dataSource = self

        addChild(pageViewController)
        pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)

        pageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

        let views: [String: Any] = ["pageView": pageViewController.view]

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[pageView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[pageView]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

        guard let startingViewController = detailViewControllerAt(index: currentViewControllerIndex) else {
            return
        }

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    func detailViewControllerAt(index: Int) -> DataViewController? {

        if index >= dataSource.count || dataSource.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        guard let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: DataViewController.self)) as? DataViewController else {
            return nil
        }

        detailViewController.index = index
        detailViewController.displayText = dataSource[index]

        return detailViewController
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        print ("presentationIndex \(currentViewControllerIndex)")

        return currentViewControllerIndex
    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        print ("presentationCount \(dataSource.count)")

        return dataSource.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let dataViewController = viewController as? DataViewController

        guard var currentIndex = dataViewController?.index else {
            return nil
        }

        print ("viewControllerBefore \(currentIndex)")

        if (currentIndex == 0) {
            return nil
        }

        currentIndex -= 1

        currentViewControllerIndex = currentIndex

        return detailViewControllerAt(index: currentIndex)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let dataViewController = viewController as? DataViewController

        guard var currentIndex = dataViewController?.index else {
            return nil
        }

        print ("viewControllerBefore \(currentIndex)")

        if currentIndex == dataSource.count-1 {
            return nil
        }

        currentIndex += 1

        currentViewControllerIndex = currentIndex

        return detailViewControllerAt(index: currentIndex)
    }
}
```

However, I hardly see any example, on how to optimize `UIPageViewController`, to handle large number of pages.

Re-creating new `UIViewController` for every page doesn't seem like a optimal solution as it will be slow. It also take up unnecessary memory space, as most of the offscreen `UIViewController` is not visible.

How can we have something similar to `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` ?

Can we re-use those previous created, currently not visible `UIViewController`?

Any code example, or tutorial resource on how to implement this correctly, is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to look up "Object Pool Pattern". Sadly there're no out-of-the-box solutions in Swift (or ObjC) but you can look at a tutorial here https://theswiftdev.com/2018/12/09/swift-object-pool-design-pattern/
BTW, I haven't tried the code in the tutorial.

Comment: You can use UICollectionView also upto some extent

Comment: What number of pages do you suggest? Is it 100, 1000? UIViewController is not as heavy as its view, so you can just remove the view when page has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Creating controllers on the fly can cause some glitches, so I typically have some array like `var viewControllers: [UIViewController]` where I store my pages
and implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`

```
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = viewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index > 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        currentViewControllerIndex = index - 1
        return viewControllers[currentViewControllerIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = viewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index < viewControllers.count - 1 else {
            return nil
        }

        currentViewControllerIndex = index + 1
        return viewControllers[currentViewControllerIndex]
    }
```

To reduce memory usage you can just deallocate view of the view controller on page change:

```
    var currentViewControllerIndex = 0 {
        didSet {
            let range = currentViewControllerIndex - 1...currentViewControllerIndex + 1

            for (offset, element) in viewControllers.enumerated() {
                if range ~= offset {
                    element.loadViewIfNeeded()
                } else {
                    element.view = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sound like a plan. May I know, is this a common pattern used by iOS community? Have you come across any article which describe this?

Comment: No, actually this is what I just invented ) Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: The strategy of deallocating view when you're out of memory is rare to find. I was told about it by my lead. He told that this is what apple's guide say. Still I haven't found this in apple's guide in one place, but reading about UIViewController lifecycle methods and a bit of code helps to understand how really UIViewController manages its view

Comment: How about UI state restoration of the page? (For instead, the y-scroll position of UICollectionView) Do we need an array to keep track of every UI page state, and then restore accordingly, manually?

Comment: Sure. Suppose you have your `pageVc` which is your item controller. Probably it is convenient to create some `struct State` (you can nest it inside your class definition and call `YourItemViewController.State`) to have all data to set up and apply it on `viewDidLoad`. Since the view was deallocated, `pageVc.view` will be nil and by default a new one will be created. After the new view is created `viewDidLoad` is called. So you can apply your state here